# Find URNs for Organizations that a user is associated with in v2 api?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

Long story short I am trying to figure out what endpoint to call within the v2 API that will return a response in which I can extract the URN for the organizations they are admins for. I will then use that URN in a different api call to find out more information about the company itself (mainly vanityName and/or localizedName).

Our product is trying to verify that the user who logs in is associated with the company from our product.

Previously we used this: `$getCompanyInfoLinkedinUrl = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true&oauth2_access_token=' . $accessToken;`

I am looking for the equivalent of that call using the new v2 organization api endpoints. So far I have had no luck. This is in PHP fyi.

I can give more code if necessary but the authorization and access token parts are working fine. It's the authentication request I can't get to work as expected.

Note: We got access to the Marketing Developer Platform but not Compliance (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/) not sure if that is the endpoint I am looking for or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Organization Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control#find-access-control-information) endpoint, as [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control#using-projections):

```
curl  -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationAcls?q=roleAssignee&projection=(elements*(*,roleAssignee~(localizedFirstName,localizedLastName),organization~(id,localizedName)))&oauth2_access_token=<AUTH_TOKEN>


{
  "elements": [
    {
      "organization~": {
        "localizedName": "<name>",
        "id": 35477867
      },
      "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
      "organization": "urn:li:organization:35477867",
      "roleAssignee": "urn:li:person:WHJGDUaMt8",
      "state": "APPROVED",
      "roleAssignee~": {
        "localizedLastName": "xxx",
        "localizedFirstName": "yyy"
      }
    },
    {
      "organization~": {
        "localizedName": "name",
        "id": 35486968
      },
      "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
      "organization": "urn:li:organization:35486968",
      "roleAssignee": "urn:li:person:WHJGDUaMt8",
      "state": "APPROVED",
      "roleAssignee~": {
        "localizedLastName": "xxx",
        "localizedFirstName": "yyy"
      }
    },
    {
      "organization~": {
        "localizedName": "name",
        "id": 35516406
      },
      "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
      "organization": "urn:li:organization:35516406",
      "roleAssignee": "urn:li:person:WHJGDUaMt8",
      "state": "APPROVED",
      "roleAssignee~": {
        "localizedLastName": "xxx",
        "localizedFirstName": "yyy"
      }
    },
    {
      "organization~": {
        "localizedName": "name",
        "id": 35516410
      },
      "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
      "organization": "urn:li:organization:35516410",
      "roleAssignee": "urn:li:person:WHJGDUaMt8",
      "state": "APPROVED",
      "roleAssignee~": {
        "localizedLastName": "xxx",
        "localizedFirstName": "yyy"
      }
    },
    {
      "organization~": {
        "localizedName": "name",
        "id": 35473047
      },
      "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
      "organization": "urn:li:organization:35473047",
      "roleAssignee": "urn:li:person:WHJGDUaMt8",
      "state": "APPROVED",
      "roleAssignee~": {
        "localizedLastName": "xxx",
        "localizedFirstName": "yyy"
      }
    },
    {
      "organization~": {
        "localizedName": "name",
        "id": 12984729
      },
      "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
      "organization": "urn:li:organization:12984729",
      "roleAssignee": "urn:li:person:WHJGDUaMt8",
      "state": "APPROVED",
      "roleAssignee~": {
        "localizedLastName": "xxx",
        "localizedFirstName": "yyy"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Also [List companies where member has a role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/company-pages-migration#list-companies-where-member-has-a-role) endpoint could be helpful

Hope this help

Comment: This ended up working. The issue I was having was a new "test user" didn't have the ability to create a company page. And a company page is different from a group. So the reason it kept responding with empty was because there were no companies associated with that user. This endpoint works for our needs. Thanks!